# WiX: Dynamic product name

Tags: wix, wix3.10

How can I dynamically set my product name in my product.wxs file?

My idea was to create a custom dialog where the user can choose between either `2015`, `2016` or `2017` via radio buttons.
The year is supposed to be the suffix for my product name:

```
 <Product Id="*"
          Name="BlaBla 2015"
          Language="1033"
          Version="$(var.SomePluginVersion)"
          Manufacturer="MyCompany"
          UpgradeCode="{SOME-GUID}">
```

I guess the custom dialog has to set a preprocessor variable so the product name can be defined before the actual installation process.
But how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProductName is a property, you can just set it to any value you want dynamically. For example:

```
<Property Id="Year">2016</Property>

<CustomAction Id="SetProductName" Property="ProductName" Value="Product [Year]" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="SetProductName" After="InstallInitialize"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: Wow that was easier than I expected. Having some difficulties in WiX every now and then because I'm not used to the syntax, yet.
Thanks so much, Nikolay.

Comment: Yep, the syntax is a bit creepy, but that's basically not WiX but windows installer design issue..

Comment: Yes I tend to mix them up quite often. Thanks again.

Comment: Always useful to take a look at your MSI with Orca and look at the database tables or decompile an msi with Dark to see how to do something with Wix

Comment: This does not work for me. In my case the name remains Name="BlaBla 2015". Any suggestion will be welcomed. Thank you.